# Loop won't stop at end of file

Tags: c++, file, loops, io

I'm working on file io, and i've managed to get the data from the file into the vector i made, but when i print the values, i get garbage numbers after the last part of the data. So i'm guessing its pushing values that don't exist into the vector, or its trying to print parts of the vector that don't exist. Any help would be great.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "store.h"

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    store data;
    ifstream inFile ("C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Albums.csv");
    string line;
    string item;
    int num;
    int itemnum;
    int linenum = 1;
    ostringstream convert;
    string temp;
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        while (getline (inFile, line) )
        {
            istringstream linestream(line);
            itemnum = 0;
            num = 0;
            convert << linenum;
            temp = convert.str();
            data.addtovectv(temp);
            while (getline (linestream, item, ',') )
            {
                if (itemnum == 1 || itemnum == 2 || itemnum == 3 || itemnum == 5)
                {
                    num++;
                    data.addtovectfullline(0, item);
                }
                itemnum++;
            }
            linenum++;
        }
    }
    data.print();
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

store.h

```
#ifndef STORE_H
#define STORE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class store
{
    public:
        store();
        void addtovectv(string);
        void addtovectfullline(int, string);
        void print();

    private:
        vector<string> v;
        vector< vector<string> > fullline;
};

#endif
```

store.cpp

```
#include "store.h"

store::store()
{

}
void store::addtovectv(string a)
{
    v.push_back(a);
    fullline.push_back(v);
}
void store::addtovectfullline(int a, string c)
{
    fullline[a].push_back(c);
}
void store::print()
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<fullline.size(); i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<fullline[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << fullline[i][j] << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

edit:  some sample data

RS 500 compilations, Various Artists,   The Sun Records Collection, 308

Both lists, A Tribe Called Quest, The Low End Theory, 1991, 154, Jive, Skeff Anselm,    Zombart JK, USA,    48:08:52

Both lists, AC/DC,  Back in Black, 1980, 73, ATCO, Robert John Lange, Bob Defrin,   Australia / UK, 41:36:52

Both lists, AC/DC,  Highway to Hell, 1979, 199, Albert Productions, Robert John Lange,  Bob Defrin  Australia / UK, 41:53:52

i need to read the lines, but only put the second, third, fourth, and sixth piece of info into the vectors, which is what it should end up printing, with each individual piece on a new line. All the data is stored in a .csv file

with this sample data, my output is this screenshot: http://puu.sh/bHtHM.png
however, none of those numbers at the bottom should be there, and there is a weird space after the first set of data

edit2: realized that odd space was an absence of the data i asked for, so its fine

Comment: Please provide an example input and expected vs actual output.

Comment: okay, did that, sorry

Comment: Please be more clear about the exact format of the output you expect. Just paste it, verbatim.

Comment: `while (inFile.eof())` - this loop will never be entered. Your description does not match this code.

Answer (score 0):

`In.good()` is not the appropriate way to tell if the file is done.

(From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/)

`Ios::eof()` checks for end of file.

`Ios::Good()` checks for no errors in opening. It probably exits the loop when an error occurs from reading past `EOF`.

Comment: i tried changing it to !inFile.eof(), but that did the same

Comment: I think the issue arises from the second getline. It would be possible to have an uneven number of lines, and since it doesn't check for EOF, it would go out of bounds.

Comment: okay, i added an EOF check for that getline as well, but now it launches and never prints any data, doesn't even end the program

Comment: The outer loop checking for `inFile.good()` is completely redundant. I doubt it is part of the problem. The inner loop reads until failure. And with getline, that usually means end of file. So both `!inFile.eof()` and `inFile.good()` would serve the same purpose there, and that purpose is completely redundant with the inner loop.